# Identify cases where data sequence changes based on other column UserIDs

Tags: r, group-by, sequence, multiple-columns, rolling-computation

I am working on a data frame `df` which is as below:

###### Input:

```
TUserId  SUID   mid_sum final_sum
 115      201   2       7     
 115      309   1       8     
 115      404   1       9           
 209      245   2       10    
 209      398   2       10          
 209      510   2       10
 209      602   1       10
 371      111   2       11
 371      115   1       11
 371      123   3       11
 371      124   2       11
```

1- My data is arranged in a `wide`  format, where each row has a unique student ID shown as `SUID`.

2- Several students can have the same teacher and hence the common teacher ID across multiple rows shown as `TUserId`.

3- The data includes student scores in mid-terms and then students' final scores.

4- I am interested in finding out if there are any instances where a teacher who gave similar scores to their students on mid-terms as shown by `mid_sum` gave inconsistent scores on their final exams as shown by `final_sum`. If such inconsistency is found in data, I want to add a column `Status` that records this `inconsistency`.

###### Requirement:

a- For this, my rule is that if `mid_sum` and `final_sum` are sorted in ascending order, as I have done in this example data frame `df`. I want to identify the cases where the ascending sequence breaks in either of these columns `mid_sum` and `final_sum`.

b- Can it be done, if the data is not sorted?

###### Example 1:

For example, for `SUID = 309`, `mid_sum` is a decrement from the previous `mid_sum`. So it should be marked as `inconsistent`. It should only happen for students who were marked by the same teacher `TUserId`, which in this case is `115`.

###### Example 2:

Similarly,  for `SUID = 602`, `mid_sum` is a decrement from the previous `mid_sum`. So it should be marked as `inconsistent`. Again, it is for the same teacher `TUserId = 209`

To elaborate further, I want an output like this:

###### Output:

```
TUserId  SUID   mid_sum final_sum   Status
 115      201   2       7           consistent
 115      309   1       8           inconsistent
 115      404   1       9           consistent
 209      245   2       10          consistent
 209      398   2       10          consistent
 209      510   2       10          consistent
 209      602   1       10          inconsistent
 371      111   2       11          consistent
 371      115   1       11          inconsistent
 371      123   3       11          consistent
 371      124   2       11          inconsistent
```

##### Data import dput()

The `dput()` for the data frame is below:

```
dput(df)

structure(list(
TUserId = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 371L, 371L, 371L, 371L), 
SUID = c(201L, 309L, 404L, 245L, 398L, 510L, 602L, 111L, 115L, 123L, 124L), 
mid_sum = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), 
final_sum = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

I looked for similar questions on SO and found this [R - identify consecutive sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439273/r-identify-consecutive-sequences) but it does not seem to help me address my question.
Another related post was [Determine when a sequence of numbers has been broken in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462438/determine-when-a-sequence-of-numbers-has-been-broken-in-r) but again, it does not help in my case.

Any advice on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `accumulate` family of functions has been designed for these situations.  Using `accumulate2` here -

- As first argument I am passing through `mid_sum`
- second argument is lagged value i.e. `lag(mid_sum)` with default as any value except `NA` and actual values it may take.  I am taking `0` as safe
- `.init` is provided with any value.  I chose `c` only.
- if first argument `(..2)` [..1 is accumulated value and not first arg] is less than `..3` i.e. second argument, return `inconsistent` else `consistent`.
- Now since `.init` is provided the results will be one value large than provided, so stripped its first value `[-1]`

```r
df <- structure(list(
  TUserId = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 371L, 371L, 371L, 371L), 
  SUID = c(201L, 309L, 404L, 245L, 398L, 510L, 602L, 111L, 115L, 123L, 124L), 
  mid_sum = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), 
  final_sum = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(TUserId, final_sum) %>%
  group_by(TUserId) %>%
  mutate(status = unlist(accumulate2(mid_sum, lag(mid_sum, default = 0), .init = 'c', 
                              ~ if(..2 < ..3) 'inconsistent' else 'consistent')[-1]))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 5
#> # Groups:   TUserId [3]
#>    TUserId  SUID mid_sum final_sum status      
#>      <int> <int>   <int>     <int> <chr>       
#>  1     115   201       2         7 consistent  
#>  2     115   309       1         8 inconsistent
#>  3     115   404       1         9 consistent  
#>  4     209   245       2        10 consistent  
#>  5     209   398       2        10 consistent  
#>  6     209   510       2        10 consistent  
#>  7     209   602       1        10 inconsistent
#>  8     371   111       2        11 consistent  
#>  9     371   115       1        11 inconsistent
#> 10     371   123       3        11 consistent  
#> 11     371   124       2        11 inconsistent
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @AnilGoyal, I tried this on my original data frame. R shows little error signs ```x``` at the start and the end of the mutate statement within the RStudio environment.
I am wondering why is that the case?

Comment: @Sandy, but in my RStudio, there is no error.  I rechecked

Comment: @Sandy, can you please tell what's the error?

Comment: Can I upload an image/snapshot of my screen, is there a way to do that?

Comment: When I run the command, it does not print any error messages but just on the screen there are little ```x```'s.

Comment: you have to upload that on imgur/drive and then post a link in comments

Comment: I think these might now when you restart a session

Comment: I will try restarting the session, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly straightforward way where we test the sign of the lagged difference. If the mid_sum difference sign is the same as the final_sum difference sign, they are "consistent".

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(TUserId, final_sum) %>%
  group_by(TUserId) %>%
  mutate(
    Status = if_else(
      sign(final_sum + 0.1 - lag(final_sum, default = 0)) == sign(mid_sum + 0.1 - lag(mid_sum, default = 0)),
      "consisent", "inconsistent"
    )
  )
# # A tibble: 11 x 5
# # Groups:   TUserId [3]
#    TUserId  SUID mid_sum final_sum Status      
#      <int> <int>   <int>     <int> <chr>       
#  1     115   201       2         7 consisent   
#  2     115   309       1         8 inconsistent
#  3     115   404       1         9 consisent   
#  4     209   245       2        10 consisent   
#  5     209   398       2        10 consisent   
#  6     209   510       2        10 consisent   
#  7     209   602       1        10 inconsistent
#  8     371   111       2        11 consisent   
#  9     371   115       1        11 inconsistent
# 10     371   123       3        11 consisent   
# 11     371   124       2        11 inconsistent
```

The `+ .1` serves to make rows where the scores stay the same count as a positive sign.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor Thomas, this seems to be working perfectly on my data. I will accept it as my solution.

Comment: Hi @Gregor Thomas, a quick question: Is it possible to modify your code so that the row number ```10``` from your results becomes ```inconsistent```? 

It is with reference to the row where ```TUserId = 371```,  ```SUID = 123```, ```mid_sum = 3``` and ```final_sum=11```?

Could you please advise on this?

Comment: Can you explain the logic? In row 3 `mid_sum` stays the same and `final_sum` increases - this is marked "consistent". Is that correct? But when the reverse happens in row 10, `mid_sum` increases by `final_sum` stays the same, you want that marked as inconsistent? But also if both stay the same as in row 5, that is consistent? Is that right?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. 'Yes' to all of your questions (for rows # 3, 5 and 10).